# WordPress footer not at bottom

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have been editing a WordPress website for the first time and now I have had a problem where the main content div overflows the footer and i'm not sure how to deal with this.
Here is the website:

www.twazzle.co.uk/twazzle/wordpress/

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: not sure what i'm looking at here. i don't see anything overflowing... what part is the footer? also, what does your php code look like?

Comment: what are you expecting it to look like?  for starters, you have a bunch of absolute positioning so I would start with that....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a few problems here. One, you have floated elements inside blocks with no float or clears. Two (and this is your main problem) your `#content` div is `position:absolute` but nothing else is. With absolute positioning your divs will ignore others resulting in overlapping and other messiness. To fix, before making an element `position:absolute` make it's containing block element `position:relative`. You'll also want to fix that float problem.

```
#main { 
    overflow: hidden; //this tells it to contain floated elements inside it
    }
#primary {
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
    position: relative; //this will contain nested absolutely positioned elements
    width: 999px;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your #content and #primary elements both have absolute position, so their dimensions won't affect the layout of anything else on the page, when they grow/contract the other elements don't grow/contract to fit. Start by changing these both to position: relative or static, this will cause some other things to break due to the way the css has been written, but you'll have to take that as a starting point to fix it.